# What to use after "should be"?

Tags: tenses, should

Is it compulsory to use verb+ing with "should be"? Or can I use should be+verb+ed? My example - "something good should be reviewed" is it correct? Or "good movies should be reviewed"

Comment: It all depends on context - 1: *Young people should be **saving** for their retirement,* 2: *Young people should be **saved** from sin.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case only should + past participle works. So it’s correct to say “Good movies should be reviewED.” The previous sentence is in the passive voice and ONLY takes the past participle. If you said “Good movies should be reviewing” it would mean that the good movies should be reviewing something. Reviewing what? The sentence doesn’t make any sense. In order to use the gerund form (verb+ing) you must add something at the beginning of the sentence. Eg. Movie critics should be reviewING good movies.

Hope I helped :)